# RStudio projects capabilities

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm starting to use RStudio and I found the option of creating Projects, which enables you "to divide your work into multiple contexts, each with their own working directory, workspace, history, and source documents" according to [rstudio.com](http://www.rstudio.com).

Are projects only used for package development? If not, can you show me any other typical situation where the features written above would allow you things (besides version control) impossible (or more difficult) to do in a normal workspace?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Projects are convenient in several ways.

1. You have mentioned version control. Even if you work alone, it is useful, and it can also be used for text files, e.g. if you use markdown/knitr/Sweave combos (see Reproducible Research). I use Git with Dropbox to track my progress both for code and reports.
2. Each project has its own working directory. You can achieve that in bare R, but R studio manages this automatically.
3. The same goes for your workspace, each project has a separate one.
4. Source files you had open in re-loaded project will open automatically.

Basically, projects are useful if you have to work with, well, multiple projects. You switch between them quickly and you get the same workspace, working directory, which means loaded objects and history. As if you have never switched. It is not impossible to do this without projects, but it is much less convenient, which was your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it's quite comprehensive. Quick question. What you say in the bullet 4 doesn't also happen in a normal RStudio session (without using a project) or is different?

Comment: @Michele Impossible to compare. Rstudio will open the same document if you relaunch it, but this says nothing about the situation when you have to switch between multiple programs. You have to manually close one program and open another, then manually load the new workspace, manually change directory. Rinse and repeat when you go back. I suggest you just try using projects in RStudio, it takes 5 minutes and you will be able to decide whether it is something for you. If not, just delete the couple of extra files in your project directory, and you are back to normal.

Comment: Ok, got it! I'll definitely start playing with projects.